# In what order does skimage.measure.regionprops label the objects?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to measure the area of objects in images like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TSEf.png). The objects are aligned next to each other, and i need to know to which object each measurement belongs to in the image. I use these lines of codes:

```
from skimage import measure, io, img_as_ubyte
from skimage.color import label2rgb, rgb2gray
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border

wb = img_as_ubyte(rgb2gray(io.imread("pmtor.jpg")))
scale = 0.6
threshold = threshold_otsu(wb)
thresh_img = wb < threshold

edge_touching_removed = clear_border(thresh_img)
label_image = measure.label(edge_touching_removed, connectivity=wb.ndim)

all_props = measure.regionprops(label_image, wb)
#Can print various parameters for all objects
for prop in all_props:
    print('Label: {} Area: {}'.format(prop.label, prop.area))
```

The problem is i do not know in what order skimage.measure.regionprops labels the object. Is it left to right? right to left or some random order? I checked the documentation for it and it did not help. Does anyone know anything about this?

Thanks

Comment: If i do not label the objects in the image, i can not pass it to the regionprops. Your comments are very confusing.

Comment: In that case, your question is confusing. “in what order skimage.measure.regionprops labels the object.” You are telling me now that it doesn’t, that you pass it a labeled image. Your underlying question is “to which object each measurement belongs to in the image”. The order is given by the labels in the labeled image. Display your labeled image, look at the pixel values, and you’ll see the order.

Comment: Regionprops returns a property “label” that tells you which region in the labeled image the properties relate to.